# How to import text file to mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large `file.txt` with over 150K lines sorted like that:

```
123.20.221.30|bin|bin
123.20.191.130|bin|bin
123.20.247.46|bin|bin
123.21.23.119|bin|bin
123.21.1.175|bin|bin
123.20.211.81|bin|bin
123.21.4.142|bin|bin
```

i have already been using a code to insert ip:port which is as follow

```html
<?php 

 // Include Database
 include("database.php"); 
 
 // Configuration 

 $type = 'ssh'; //must be one of ["socks4", "socks5", "http", "ssh"]
 $username = '$proxy[1]'; // Proxy username
 $password = '$proxy[2]'; // Proxy Password

 
 $file = fopen('proxies.txt','r');
 
 if($file){
  while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false){
   
   $proxy = explode("|",$line);
   
   $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `proxy` WHERE `server`='".trim($proxy[0].':'.$proxy[1])."'");
   $checkForProxyRows = $sql->num_rows;
   
   if($checkForProxyRows != 0)
   {
    echo "Proxy already exists. Try again!";
   }
   else  
   {
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `proxy` (type, server, user, password) VALUES ('".$type."', '".trim($proxy[0])."', '".$username."', '".$password."')");
    echo "Proxies list has been successfully updated.";
   }
  }
  fclose($file);
 }else 
 {
  echo "File could not be opened.";
 }
 
?>
```

but now it doesn't insert anything, what am doing wrong & how can I proceed for this text to insert it into the database?

edit; following the comments, but now I get the result as follow

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2piN.png)

Comment: `INSERT INTO proxy (type, server, user, password) ...` you want to insert 4 values but actually only insert 2: `'".$type."'` and `'".trim($proxy[0].'| '".$username."'| '".$password."'` Turning on error reporting might help

Comment: it doesn't insert the user password but insert all in one column ( server)

Comment: Because, like I said, you only insert **two** fields. Separate your fields using `,`, not `|`

Comment: Do not put code in comments, it is quite impossible to read.  Edit your question instead.

Comment: Please read about SQL injection and do not concatenate queries as strings. In comparison use `!==` instead of `!=`, reason is again security.